# Magento 1.9 database import error in PhpMyadmin

Tags: magento-1.9

When I am trying to import SQL file to  database in to PhpMyAdmin I am receiving below error message.

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='en' dir='ltr' class='chrome chrome48'><head><meta cha' at line 1

SQL query:
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='en' dir='ltr' class='chrome chrome48'><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><style id="cfs-style">html{display: none

Error
Static analysis:
14 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected character. (near "{" at position 223)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 231)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "DOCTYPE" at position 2)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "HTML" at position 10)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "html" at position 16)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "lang" at position 21)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "'en'" at position 26)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "dir" at position 31)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "'ltr'" at position 35)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "class" at position 41)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "'chrome chrome48'" at position 47)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "head" at position 66)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "meta" at position 72)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "charset" at position 77)
```

[image]

Comment: Exceeding maximum upload data size allowed by your installation? Looks like the load is breaking off in the middle of a SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can import an SQL script with command line:

```
mysql -h thehostname -u theuser -pthepaswoord thedatabase < pathtothesqlfile
```

This has some benifits (no timeouts, speed, ...). Be aware that there is NO space between "-p" and "thepaswoord", for the other parameters there is a space between.

Answer (score 2):

check your export SQL file it shows proper data. Sometimes PHPMyAdmin not export full data and write PHP/server error in the file. Kindly Proper check your export file. If the export file shows error then you will export file in a zip or another format.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be error that when try to insert cms pages or static block 's data into tables at that time error is generated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978970/magento-importing-product-error/14980974

Also you can alternatively remove cms pages table and static block from query.
After importing the db, copy the content data from sql query and save to the system

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Db from terminal, here is the link how to do that,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546778/how-can-i-import-a-database-with-mysql-from-terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can importing a MySQL database by command line below :

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE < yout_path/file.sql
```

Example :

- my username (root),
- password (123456),
- path to sql file (app/database/file.sql),
- phpMyAdmin database name (test)

Then command to import file.sql for test database is :

```
mysql -u root -p test < /app/database/file.sql
```